# Reemplazar linea en archivo desde powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

Estoy usando `-replace` para cambiar una linea en un archivo .txt desde powershell, solamente que me da error porque la linea actual y la final va dentro de " ", como debería ponerlo, gracias.

```
get-content $FileA | foreach-object {$_ -replace "#  - "ws://127.0.0.1:8081"", "- "  ws://1.1.1.1:8081"" }| set-content $FileB
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Procura que tu pregunta contenga el mensaje de error completo que obtienes al intentar correr tu código. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que haga falta, la opción Editar está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el carácter backtick ` se pueden escapar comillas dobles

```
get-content $FileA | foreach-object {$_ -replace "#  - `"ws://127.0.0.1:8081`"", "- `"  ws://1.1.1.1:8081`"" }| set-content $FileB
```

Aunque a veces toca usar backslash + backtick desde PowerShell 5, no sé con certeza si este es el caso

```
get-content $FileA | foreach-object {$_ -replace "#  - \`"ws://127.0.0.1:8081\`"", "- \`"  ws://1.1.1.1:8081\`"" }| set-content $FileB
```

Comment: Excelente, con solo el backtick ` funcionó para mi, pura vida!!

Comment: _Pura vida, mae!_ :) Me alegra que sirviera